# Cannot use XPATH to get a value from SOAP response

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Please help me to get value (013b92124ce54924) in "`<web:prop value='013b92124ce54924' name='serviceId'></web:prop>`"

I tried to use the xpath command unsuccessful:

`/*/SOAP-ENV:Body/'ns':requestResponse/web:webapiResponse/web:data/web:prop[@name='serviceId']/@value`

My SOAP response is as below:

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>

    <ns:requestResponse xmlns:ns='http://www.phahahotel.com/BPS/sWebAPI'>

        <web:webapiResponse xmlns:web='http://www.phahahotel.com/BPS/WebService' action='CreateServiceTel' transId='10100000009' clientId='svrcore'>

            <web:respCode>0000</web:respCode>

            <web:respDescription>Success</web:respDescription>

            <web:data>

                <web:prop value='SERTYPE' name='serviceType'></web:prop>

                <web:prop value='013b92124ce54924' name='serviceId'></web:prop>

            </web:data>

        </web:webapiResponse>

    </ns:requestResponse>  

</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around ns :-

```
% xpath test.xml "/*/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns:requestResponse/web:webapiResponse/web:data/web:prop[@name='serviceId']/@value"
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
 value="013b92124ce54924"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I get error with the command you suggested:   ` Exception occurred evaluting XPath: /*/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns:requestResponse/web:webapiResponse/web:data/web:prop[@name='serviceId']/@value. Exception: XPath expression uses unbound namespace prefix ns
output to own window
`

Comment: See if replacing the ns:requestResponse by * helps